# Firestore rules based on subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have document structures like this:

```
Courses/[courseId] {
  name: string,
  description: string

  // this is a subcollection
  members/{userId} {
    user: [userId],
    role: 'trainer',
  }
}
```

Now I want to allow only the members of a course to read the course data. I am writing rules like this:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /courses/{course} {
    allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/courses/$(course)/members/$(request.auth.uid));

    match /members/{member} {
      allow read, write: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
      allow create;
    }
  }

}
```

It's just not working, giving me an error: `Null value error. for 'list'`

Update: The error is coming from this line:

```
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/courses/$(course)/members/$(request.auth.uid)
```

and specifically `$(course)`. If I replace `$(course)` with an actual course id, the error goes away. But I need it to be dynamic.

Should I change how I structure the data? If so, what is the recommended way to structure it?

Previously, I had a root collection `members` that contains the `courseId` and `userId`, acting like a n-n relationship table. However, because firestore rules don't have a `query` function, I can't control the access of a course based on the root `members` collection.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I noticed that `members` is subcolection of `courses`, while in the rules they seem to be a collections on the same level? or maybe should change closing bracket...

Comment: @vitooh I tried that, but it doesn't work. And I seem to locate the problem. question updated.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got a time to check this.... Actually what gives you this error? Can you give example course item in the database